# Check postgres replication status

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

Can someone suggest the steps to check pgsql replication status and how to identify if the replication is not happening properly?

We use streaming replication with pgsql9.0 and pgsql9.4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323355/how-to-check-the-replication-delay-in-postgresql

Answer (score 72):

I use following SQL queries to check status on Postgres v11 usually.

**On master:**

```
select * from pg_stat_replication;
```

**On replica** (streaming replication in my case):

```
select * from pg_stat_wal_receiver;
```

Comment: For vertical output replace `;` with `\x\g\x`.

Comment: Could you explain what we are supposed to see if everything is going well or if something is wrong ? sync_state : sync on the primary is a good sign ?

Comment: sync_state refers to how the replication was configured. **state** is the field to check in pg_stat_replication.

Answer (score 30):

On your master, pg_stat_replication provides data about ongoing replication:

```
select client_addr, state, sent_location, write_location,
        flush_location, replay_location from pg_stat_replication;
```

On postgresql v10:

```
select client_addr, state, sent_lsn, write_lsn,
    flush_lsn, replay_lsn from pg_stat_replication;
```

Comment: Ok, what's wrong then if the above query returns 0 rows?

Comment: 0 rows means you have no replication configured at your server. When configured correctly should get a row(s) but that doesn't mean you have replication either as the slave may not be connecting (check 'state' column)

Comment: mmmm...we had replication working fine and it failed, now it shows no rows, please see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/180062/post-mortem-analysis-postgresql-replication-failed

Answer (score 28):

Show replication status in PostgreSQL

## on server

```
postgres=# select usename,application_name,client_addr,backend_start,state,sync_state from pg_stat_replication ;

usename   | application_name |  client_addr   |         backend_start         |   state   | sync_state 
------------+------------------+----------------+-------------------------------+-----------+------------
replicator | walreceiver      | 192.168.10.132 | 2018-07-06 06:12:20.786918+03 | streaming | async
(1 row)
```

## on client

```
postgres=# select pg_is_in_recovery();
 pg_is_in_recovery 
-------------------
 t
 (1 row)


postgres=# select pg_last_xlog_receive_location();
 pg_last_xlog_receive_location 
-------------------------------
 0/540C1DB8


postgres=# select pg_last_xlog_replay_location();
 pg_last_xlog_replay_location 
------------------------------
 0/540C1DB8
 (1 row)

postgres=#    SELECT CASE WHEN pg_last_xlog_receive_location() = pg_last_xlog_replay_location()
                  THEN 0
                ELSE EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp())
              END AS log_delay;
 log_delay 
-----------
 0
 (1 row)
```

Comment: on postgres 10, this is not working entirely but
`SELECT pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp();`
gives useful information!

Comment: Compare master and slave statuses in a single query:
`select pg_last_xlog_receive_location(), pg_last_xlog_replay_location(), pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp(),
       CASE WHEN pg_last_xlog_receive_location() = pg_last_xlog_replay_location() THEN 0
            ELSE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp()) END AS log_delay;
`

Comment: To check master IP from slave, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45062/123063

Comment: @SergeyNemchinov i guess that query works only on the backup, not on the primary?

```
cloudmaster=# select pg_last_xlog_receive_location();
ERROR:  function pg_last_xlog_receive_location() does not exist
```

Comment: @MarcosDione It seems that the pg_last_xlog_receive_location() function does not exist in newer versions after 9.x

Answer (score -1):

When performing full DB replication there are multiple stages:

- **A)** full backup - `pg_basebackup` cloning database from primary to a standby server (standby is not running)
- **B)** recovery - standby server starting up (not accepting connections yet)
- **C)** WAL streaming - Both primary and standby(s) in consistent state and accepting connections

**A) Full backup**

[Since PostgreSQL 13](https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_stat_progress_basebackup.html) you can use `pg_stat_progress_basebackup` table, where you can get progress for each replication phase (from primary):

```
psql -c "select TO_CHAR(backup_streamed::decimal/backup_total*100,'fm00D00%'),phase from pg_stat_progress_basebackup;" -t
 31.79%  | streaming database files
```

The replication process has multiple phases, progress is reported per each phase:

1. `initializing`
2. `starting file transfer`
3. `streaming database files`
4. `finishing file transfer`
5. `transferring WAL`

On earlier PostgreSQL version you're left with plain disk usage:

```
$ primary=$(du -s /var/lib/postgresql/14/main/base | awk '{print $1}')
$ replica=4648394012 # same command as above only from replica
$ echo ${replica}/${primary}*100 | bc -l
34.90793993287965597200
```

`pg_stat_replication` gives you e.g. `replay_lag` which doesn't help much with overall progress. You can only estimate how many WAL you might actually need to keep.

```
psql -c "select state, client_hostname, write_lag, replay_lag, flush_lag from pg_stat_replication;"
   state   | client_hostname |    write_lag    |   replay_lag    |    flush_lag    
-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
 backup    |                 |                 |                 | 
 streaming |                 | 00:00:00.000516 | 12:23:15.991732 | 00:00:00.310261
(2 rows)
```

**B) recovery**

Standby server has finished the first stage, assuming the server was able to start (correct configuration of critical parameters). Now the `postgres` process has to replay accumulated WALs on the standby or copy them from archive (e.g. using `archive_command`) in order to reach consistent recovery state. You can obtain the [LSN](https://pgpedia.info/l/LSN-log-sequence-number.html) using `pg_controldata`:

```
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_controldata /var/lib/postgresql/14/main | grep "Minimum recovery"
Minimum recovery ending location:     4034A/1BFFFB58
```

NOTE: There's no record in `pg_stat_replication` table on the primary, at this stage.

You'll notice in logs something like:

```
FATAL:  the database system is not yet accepting connections
DETAIL:  Consistent recovery state has not been yet reached.
LOG:  restored log file "000000020004022E00000029" from archive
```

The HEX number points to a WAL file, that can be dumped (typically single line is enough)

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_waldump 14/main/pg_wal/00000002000402340000003D -n 1
rmgr: Heap        len (rec/tot):     48/    48, tx: 1350166609, lsn: 40234/F4001C08, prev 40234/F3FFFDB0, desc: HEAP_CONFIRM off 52, blkref #0: rel 1663/16421/2324630632 blk 85514
```

we're looking for the LSN part, e.g. `lsn: 40234/F4001C08`. Now, when we get back to the primary server, we can obtain the lag in file size units:

```
 psql -c "SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), '40234/F4001C08'));" -t
 1813 GB
```

`1813 GB` is the diff between current WAL and the one being replayed.

Another option is to use `pg_controldata`

```
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_controldata /var/lib/postgresql/14/main | grep location
Latest checkpoint's REDO location:    40335/C001D040
```

where you can obtain following LSN pointers:

- `Backup start location`
- `Latest checkpoint's REDO location` - current recovery position
- `Minimum recovery ending location`

**C) WAL streaming**

Primary and standby are in almost the same state, both servers are accepting connections. Except there might be some lag between those two servers, which might be caused by frequency of writes to WAL, network transfer speed, etc.

On standby:

```
psql -c "SELECT extract(epoch from now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp());"
```

On primary:

```
psql -c "select state, client_hostname, write_lag, replay_lag, flush_lag from pg_stat_replication;"
```

This will give you time difference between two servers.