# Query In-Sync Slave

Tags: postgresql, read-replication

My PostgreSQL setup uses 3-node High Availability via async replication: primary and 2 slaves. Either slave has to acknowledge the write before the primary can COMMIT.

I need to run a SQL SELECT, ideally against the in-sync slave. I could build a new connection pool against one of the slaves, but it’s dynamic as to which is in-sync.

Is there any way for me to easily run a SELECT against the in-sync slave?

Comment: The question is unclear. replication is asynchronous, but both slaves are synchronous? If both are synchronous, why does it matter which one you query?

Comment: Sorry. Both slaves are async. At least one has to ack the primary write for primary to commit.

Comment: What’s you definition of *easily*? This sounds like you want a pool that stays connected to all 3, keeping track of which standby is all caught up or always checking before deciding where to route the query, giving priority to standby’s, with primary as last resort.

Comment: So I’d have to query pg_stat_replication of primary, and then decide which standby to hit?

Comment: That's a contradiction in terms. "Standby has to acknowledge commit" is the definition of synchronous replication in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I think if its set up as [`FIRST 1 (standby1, standby2)` or ANY 1 (standby1, standby2)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-STANDBY-NAMES), then only the one’s chosen to be synchronously replicated to, leaving the other free to catch up later in an async manner.

Comment: @KevinMeredith That, or you can check that [on standby/receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51261401/5298879). There's also [`pgpool`'s load balancing](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-config-load-balancing.html) that takes care of that.

Comment: Thanks, Laurenz and Zegarek. Let me look at pg_stat_replication and report back. I appear to have not understood how ANY worked.

Comment: `SHOW synchronous_standby_names` returns `ANY 1 (*)`. In that case, there are no sync replicas?

Comment: @KevinMeredith That means there's always 1. As soon as any single one of the receivers confirms it got and applied the transaction from the primary, it's committed on both without waiting for further acknowledgements from the remaining standby's.

Comment: With a primary and A and B standby servers, if A confirms, the primary will commit? B could technically be behind or down, no? As a result to my original question I do not know if A or B is the sync?

Comment: @KevinMeredith 1. That is exactly right. 2. Correct. 3. Yes, you need to check the current replication state. ‘pgpool‘ is open-source so you can look up how exactly its load balancer does that if you’re unable to use it and need to replicate the behaviour.